# Windows XP, I cant remove network device

Tags: windows

I disabled it in the BIOS, tried in safe mode, no success: when I try to remove it, it says "cannot uninstall device - may be required for booting"

(its a network card)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is it a removable network card? If so, try removing it. Most laptops let's you remove the card and most desktops will as well so long as it's not integrated into the motherboard.

Comment: I think its integrated. But if not, why disabling it wouldnt work?